# BigInteger as kotlin.Number

Tags: kotlin, biginteger

In Kotlin, `BigInteger` comes from package java.math. So how come I can do this:

```
val x: Number = BigInteger.ONE
```

In the above statement, `Number` is `kotlin.Number` and I don't see any relationship between that and `java.math.BigInteger`.

Conversely, why is the following a compile-time error?

```
val x: java.lang.Number = BigInteger.ONE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Kotlin docs on Java interop](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types) states:

> Kotlin treats some Java types specifically. Such types are not loaded from Java "as is", but are mapped to corresponding Kotlin types. The mapping only matters at compile time, the runtime representation remains unchanged.

`java.lang.Number` class shouldn't be used in Kotlin at all (as all other mapped types). Its mapping type should be used instead (`kotlin.Number` in this case)

Comment: Also if you inspect the Java bytecode for the first statement, it's basically just casting your ``BigInteger`` value to ``Number`` (the Java one, its superclass)

Comment: Might be worth explicitly saying that `kotlin.Number` is mapped to `java.lang.Number`.